# How to add pin point on Google Map using package (when you click on a button, it open directly to Google Map App) on android studio

Tags: android

I have trouble with adding the pin point on Google Map using package for opening Google Map App to show the point of location on android studio. Here is the code

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:"+29.972653+","+31.283936);
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:<" + latitude + ">,<" + longitude + ">?q=<" + latitude + ">,<" + longitude()));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");

try {
    context.startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

    String urlAddress = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + latitude + "," + longitude;
    Intent intents = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlAddress));
    context.startActivity(intents);
}
```

It will check if GoogleMaps application is installed or not and if not then redirect you to browser

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
context.startActivity(mapIntent);
```